# SharePoint Online Plan-1 Vs Office 365 Business Essentials

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, onedrive, collaboration

I'd like to know the difference between these two plan.

I just want to use central document sharing on Cloud for easy collaborating with our team. Which one is better for my use-case?

Some conditions are confusing for me.

SharePoint Online Plan-1: https://products.office.com/ja-jp/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans

Office 365 Business Essentials: https://products.office.com/ja-jp/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?&activetab=tab:primaryr2

**Both are the same price but the included services are different.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for SharePoint as a document management system then first look at both plan in details:

**SharePoint Online Plan-1**

**Services Provided in this plan:**

SharePoint & OneDrive

License Cost: 330 INR /User/Month

**Major features under this plan are:**

- 1 TB of OneDrive storage per user
- Share files securely inside or outside your organization
- Sync local copies of files or folders for offline viewing and editing
  on Mac or PC
- Co-author in real time in familiar Microsoft Office apps
- Inform and connect your people with intranets and portals
- Tell your story with beautiful communication sites
- Use team sites to connect teams to content, expertise, and processes
- Organize and manage content in libraries and lists with metadata,
  records management, and retention policies
- Move and manage files between OneDrive and SharePoint
- Search and discover relevant people and important content when you
  need it most
- Navigate your team sites and intranet with the SharePoint mobile apps
  for Android™, iOS, and Windows or OneDrive mobile apps for Android™, 
  iOS and Windows5
- FastTrack deployment support with purchase of 50+ seats at no extra
  cost
- 24/7 phone and web support
- Licensed for commercial use

**Limitation on this plan**

- We cannot install any office product

**Office 365 Business Essentials**

Major services are:

- Exchange
- OneDrive
- SharePoint
- Teams

**Key features in this plan:**

- Host email with a 50 GB mailbox and custom email domain address.
- Create a hub for teamwork to connect your teams with Microsoft Teams.
- Access web versions of Office apps: Outlook, Word, Excel,
  PowerPoint, OneNote (plus Access and Publisher for PC only).
- Store and share files with 1 TB of OneDrive cloud storage.
- Host online meetings and video conferencing for up to 250 users.
- Get help anytime with around-the-clock phone and web support from
  Microsoft.

License Cost: 125 INR /User/Month

Here the license cost is lesser than the **SharePoint Online Plan-1**

**Conclusion:**

We can go with the **Office 365 Business Essentials** plan as we are getting more services (**Microsoft Teams** which is very important for the communication, Exchange) than the other plan **SharePoint Online Plan-1** with the less price.

Comment: Do you know why Office 365 Business Essentials plan is cheaper and get more services than the SharePoint Online Plan-1.

Comment: You can speak to a sales expert,  they will clarify you and give you more details, customer support is the right channel to get it clarified :-)